# Use double-click to see diffs for pending changes using VisualSVN in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, svn, developer-tools, visualsvn

I am new to VisualSVN, coming from AnkhSvn. **I am using the "Pending Changes" window to review my changes to the solution.**

When I double-click into the tree of files, I get the file opened for display in Visual Studio 2015.

[image: Context menu of VisualSVN for pending changes]

This is the first menu entry in the context menu. **How to change this behaviour, to open the diff tool on double-click instead?**

Note: Opening the diff tool works with the context menu and also with the keyboard shortcut (CTRL+D), but my workflow would be faster, if I could just double-click to see the diffs.

Note2: This is a copy of question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/384274/use-double-click-to-see-diffs-for-pending-changes-using-visualsvn-in-visual-stud on SE, but since it is off-topic there and on-topic here, I copy-migrated it.

Comment: You can configure the behavior of double-click in the Pending Changes window. See the updated answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the behavior of double-click in the Pending Changes window. Follow these steps:

1. Start **Visual Studio**.
2. On the menu bar, choose **VisualSVN | Options**.
3. On the left pane, click **Code Review**.
4. Select the **Show changes on double click** option and click **OK**.

[image]

Comment: WOW, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks! Hopefully, now, Google will find this here.